# Open paradox / borland database as single file

Tags: java, database, database-connection, paradox

my question is:
how to connect java tp paradox / borland database ".DB" single files?

Here's what I have:
[image: screenshot]
So, it's Paradox 7 database files.

I'm trying drivers:
http://www.hxtt.com/paradox.html & https://code.google.com/archive/p/paradoxdriver/ as:

```
String url = "jdbc:paradox:/D:/BABAK/powerGold/SongTitle.DB";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

But both throws exceptions like:

```
D:/BABAK/powerGold/SongTitle.DB isn't a database directory path!
```

As you can see, it is trying to find some database folder, but I have only single files! Also, "jdbc:paradox:/D:/BABAK/powerGold" (path to all .DB files folder) didn't work as well.

So, anybody, please help me to figure out, how to open this type of DB in my Java app.

Answer (score 1):

`jdbc:paradox:D:/BABAK/powerGold` is the correct syntax.

One of the open source Paradox drivers you mentioned is [now on Github](https://github.com/leonhad/paradoxdriver) and has had more features added since a couple of years ago, so that may now work.

If it doesn't, can you post the full stack trace (using this library, not the HXTT one) so we can figure out exactly what's going on? I'm not the original author, but I have made several contributions for different field types.

Answer (score 0):

you're not trying to open the database doing so  but a  specific  file of the whole DB. In fact your DB is composed of files .db, .px ....

The best approach to do so, is to migrate since this  DB  is not supported, and realy brings a lot of bugs.

I will  recommand  you  to use migrate  your database.

1. install Paradox Database Reader or  Editor
2. export tables to CSV files
3. import tables in mysql Database (for  example)

If  you still  want to connect this DB without migration with  java, share in  private a file .db and  will give a try now.

Comment: hello! Migration isn't possible: it's a live DB of an everyday used software, so, I need some way to connect & open it, as Paradox Data Editor does. Sending you a .DB file on Twitter (and here's the link: http://6zo.ru/powerGold_DB_Example.zip , there's nothing secret inside)

Answer (score 0):

To solve it do the following:

1. `String url = "jdbc:paradox:/D:/BABAK/powerGold/";`
2. keep the same files .db and .px of SongTitle in the same directory then run your code and it will work

Comment: I'll try, but take a look to question:
> Also, "jdbc:paradox:/D:/BABAK/powerGold" (path to all .DB files folder) didn't work as well.